# Logical AND in Clojure

Tags: clojure, logic

Is Clojure's logical `and` different from the normal logical `and` (&&)? Why does this yield true

```
((and odd? #(> 10 %)) 6)
```

Doesn't `and` need 2 true statements to return true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` doesn't necessarily return `true`. It actually returns `false` or `nil` if any of the given elements is `false` or `nil`. If none of them are, then it returns the very last element (it does not return true).

In your case the `and` returns the function `#(> 10 %)` (and nothing else) which is then applied to `6` which yields true. This is because both functions are neither `nil` nor `false`.
This is how the steps would work:

```
((and odd? #(> 10 %)) 6)
(#(> 10 %) 6) 
;; => true
```

What you're looking for is to compose predicate functions:

```
((every-pred odd? #(> 10 %)) 6) ;; => false
```

FYI: There is also it's complement "`or`": `some-fn`.

Comment: But `(odd? 6)` Is false. Why does it proceed to the next expression? According the definition of the logical and it returns false if its first element returns false.

Comment: That means `and` doesn't evaluate (in the way i've written the code) `(odd? 6)` AND `(> 10 6)`?  But instead looks literally for `false` or `nil`?

Comment: `and` doesn't know of the `6` and it doesn't compose the functions. If you want to compose functions you had `every-pred` and it's complement `some-fn`

Comment: Amir, think of it this way: Every object in Clojure is true (including the object `true`, and all functions, among other things), except for `nil` and `false`, which are the only objects that are false.  Anything that evaluates to a true object is of course counted as true, and anything that evaluates to a false object is of course counted as false.  Sometimes people use the terms "truthy" and "falsey" for this distinction.